# How do you communicate that UI is not the same as UX

Tags: usability, design, ux-field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between UI and UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7174/difference-between-ui-and-ux)

One of the challenges that I have found is communicating the fact that UI is not the same as UX and is just  a subset of of UX as a whole .The general argument is that we create nice icons and layouts and decide on effective color codes and hence it makes it easier for users to use the application,hence this is UX work but when you bring up the concept of iterative low fidelity prototyping or usability testing ,I just get blank looks.

How do you communicate something like this ?

Comment: Get right in their face and shout "UI AND UX ARE DIFFERENT THINGS, IDIOT" ;) Seriously, I sympathise, because a lot of clients are really able to appreciate the complexity of the new world where these things matter.

Comment: Who are you trying to explain this to and for what purpose?

Comment: Duplicate of https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35537/what-are-the-real-differences-between-ui-ux-and-front-end-development